# Error when trying role switching in Snowflake setup using External Auth (Azure Active Directory)

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have setup Snowflake SSO using External Auth (Azure Active Directory). I followed the Snowflake Documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure

From my application when I try to get access token. I get the following error

The authorization server reported a failed authorization attempt: {"error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "AADSTS650053: The application '<app_name>' asked for scope '' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'

Although there are multiple posts on this error I was not able to get this to work and still have some questions about the error.

1. Created the Resource App and Client App in Azure Portal
2. From the snowflake documentation, I am following step number 10 and step number 13
3. Adding Snowflake roles in scope in the Resource App. and then in the Client App. adding the roles as api permissions.

I am not defining the Application ID URI as the documentation mentions a option to not define the application id uri and then in the Snowflake Security Integration the audience list can be set to Snowflake Account URL.

[image]

```
If the Application ID URI is not used, then it is necessary to create a security integration with audiences using the Snowflake Account URL (i.e. <account_identifier>.snowflakecomputing.com).
```

The error indicates that role is being searched in the Microsoft Graph resource which confused me and I could not understand why that happens. The role exists under my Resource App. in the API permissions in the Client App.

I looked at Microsoft Documentation and that seems to indicate that incase Application ID URI is not specified then the scope will be searched in the Microsoft Graph Resource [image]

I find the documentation on Snowflake and Microsoft conflicting, any pointers on if I am missing something here related to the documentation would be very helpful.

Post this I decided to update my Azure Apps. by adding a Application ID URI in the Resource App. and also updated the Security Integration in Snowflake, the audience list parameter in the security integration.

Then from my application, I used the JDBC URI like

```
snowflake://<.....>.snowflakecomputing.com:<myport>/?warehouse=<whatever_warehouse>&db=<whatever_db>&authenticator=oauth&role="https://<tenant-id>/session:scope:<myrolename>"
```

`myrolename` scope is defined in the azure apps.

When I tried the above URI, my flow got past the error and I was able to retrieve an access_token.
Decoded the access_token and that looked fine and also verified the access_token on Snowflake
using
SELECT SYSTEM$VERIFY_EXTERNAL_OAUTH_TOKEN('access_token');

This returned success and with the proper correct user claim.

But when the flow tried to establish a connection I got Illegal Argument Error for the role parameter in the uri, was looking if there are any suggestions on this.

Comment: In your JDBC connection string the `role` argument needs to have the value of a role and not a URL, so something like `role=public` would be accepted.

Comment: Hello @Sergiu Thank you for taking time and adding a response here. I changed the role value as suggested and that worked :). Any pointers about the Application ID uri ? Snowflake documentation indicates I can skip adding the application id uri but when I do skip it and try to use the auth setup, Azure searches for the scope/role under Microsoft Graph resource (`00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`) which indicates I need to have a application ID uri. I find the 2 documentations contradicting, any pointers will be super helpful for my understanding :).  Thank You, Salil

Comment: If you do not want to use Application ID then you need to change in Snowflake the security integration to use Audiences as Snowflake account URL like `external_oauth_audience_list = ('https://<account>.<region>.azure.snowflakecomputing.com')`. That is what the explanation is about in the screenshot you added from Snowflake docs.

Comment: Hello @Sergiu, thank you for the responses. Really appreciate the help. I was able to get the Snowflake + Azure Active Directory External Auth setup working end to end and also able to perform role switching by specifying role value in the jdbc uri.

Comment: This is for reference in case it helps so for default scope I specified SESSION:ROLE-ANY (a SF role). I get the access token by sending only this role when I make the authorization request. For the role mentioned in the jdbc uri I do not add it in the authorization request. The authentication completes and when I run SELECT CURRENT_ROLE query I can see that the role is as specified in the jdbc uri.